# How to map a JSON to create an array in ReactJS?

Tags: arrays, json, reactjs, dictionary

I have a JSON and i need to map it and create 2 arrays. One array with field ART and the other with field SALIDA.

[console.log(w_data)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YqMpH.jpg)

[reactjs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JII6A.jpg)

```
const VerTotales = ({props}) => {
let data_x = [];
let data_y = [];
let w_data = props.data;
console.log(w_data)

// data_x =
// data_y =

return (
    <Responsive
        xsmall={
            <div style={{width: 140, margin: '1em'}}>

            </div>
        }
        medium={
            <div>
                <GraficoBarrasLineaBasica
                    wp_data_x={data_x}
                    wp_data_y={data_y}
                />
            </div>
        }
    />
);
```

}

Thanks

Comment: 1. JSON is a string format that represents arrays, objects, etc., so unless you have a string, you do not have "a JSON" 2. paste relevant code and data here are formatted text, not as images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably slightly unneccesarily complicated and I used reduce rather than map but I thought I'd try to provide something for a more general case:

```js
const w_data = {
  1: { id: 1, art: 'A', salida: 100 },
  2: { id: 2, art: 'B', salida: 200 }
};

const collect_by_keys = (array_of_objects, keys) =>
  array_of_objects.reduce(
    (acc, obj) => {
      keys.forEach((k, i) => acc[i].push(obj[k]));
      return acc;
    },
    Array.from({ length: keys.length }, () => [])
  );


const [data_x, data_y] = collect_by_keys(Object.values(w_data), ['art', 'salida']);

console.log(...data_x);
console.log(...data_y);
```

Answer (score 0):

here its my idea:

```js
w_data.map((value) => {
  info.push(value.art)
  info2.push(value.salida)
})
```

Btw I suggest that you need to use Hooks and it will be something like this

```js
const [data, setData] = React.useState([
  {
    id: 1,
    art: 'data1',
    salida: 1123
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    art: 'data2',
    salida: 222
  },
])
const [array, setArray] = React.useState([])
const [arraytwo, setArrayTwo] = React.useState([])

React.useEffect(() => {
  data.map(value => {
    setArray(data => [...data, value.art])
    setArrayTwo(data => [...data, value.salida])
  })
}, [])
```

Just only you will need to replace names and property for the data that you have

Comment: I tryed with your first code, but it says "TypeError: w_data.map is not a function".

Comment: Using map() just to loop an array is not a good practice

Comment: @charlietfl You are right is better to use forEach :)